# Require Example of Material AutoComplete with http get request

Tags: material-design, angular-material, angular-material2, angular4-forms

I am following the Angular Material AutoComplete example as in the Material documents.

It works fine, when using the options[] value as per the document. It is just that I am not able to get it to work when I get the data from api.
If I do not use the filter options, then the list of books are displayed. It is just that when filters are used it has issues.

The this.filterOptions complains

> Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type
>   'Observable'.   Type 'Book[]' is not assignable to type
>   'string[]'.
>       Type 'Book' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Why did it not complain when options[] was used.

```
 export class AutocompleteComponent implements OnInit {

  myControl = new FormControl();
  //Works with these values
  options = [
    'One',
    'Two',
    'Three'
  ];
  books: Book[] = [];
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>

  constructor(private bookService: BookService) {
    this.bookService.getBooks()
      .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.books = data;
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(err.statusText);
      }
      );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .startWith('')
      .map(val => {
        return this.filter(val)
      })
  }

  filter(val: string): Book[] {
    return this.books.filter(option =>
      option.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: You declare `filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>` but assign it `Book[]`. Why?

Comment: Did you try just changing `filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>` to `filteredOptions: Observable<Book[]>`?

Comment: @gdoron It worked.  Also I had to add the this.filteredOptions inside the subscribe(). Thnx.